# Is it possible to use UpdateModel in a controller to populate an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to effectively do something like this in an MVC controller:

```
var vmObject = Activator.CreateInstance("A string representing the model that was posted");
//vmObject is of type object
TryUpdateModel(vmObject);// this would populate the object with the posted values, so that later on I could cast the object to strongly typed model similar to what was posted (not currently working)

//elsewhere in code (ie in a service that is injected into the controller)
var stronglyTypedVM = (MyViewModel)vmObject;//this instance would be populated with values from the controller
```

The reason for this is that the controller does not know the type of the view model that will be posted at compile time, yet the service that is injected into it does.

So far I have not been able to get `TryUpdateModel` to work with an object (nothing appears to be populated).

Is there a way to get this object populated from posted values? Am I going about this completely the wrong way? Can anyone suggest a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I use this trick all the time:

```
TryUpdateModel((dynamic)vmObject);
```

The reason you've been having trouble is that `TryUpdateModel` is a generically-typed method which uses the generic type to determine which properties it should look for. This could be useful if you only wanted to bind specific properties that are declared on an interface, for example. However, when all you know at compile-time is that it's an `object`, it doesn't know about any properties that can be bound on `object`s.

By casting the object to be `dynamic`, you allow the system to determine the most appropriate generic signature to use at runtime, based on the runtime type of the object. It's the same as using reflection to generate and invoke a custom generic method signature, but it's far more concise (and has slightly better performance).